# Fractal vocabulary

Tags: single-word-requests

A book is typically divided into sections, chapters,  paragraphs. I'm looking for a noun that can be used to describe all of these - **book**, sections, chapters, **figures**, clusters of paragraphs and individual paragraphs - in a way that can be used recursively.

I'm thinking perhaps something around the word "idea", but not sure what exactly and would appreciate other suggestions.

Updated: I'd like a word that applies equally well to books as well.

Updated again: If possible, I'd like also to be able to apply it to diagrams, tables and other such figures.

It does not need to apply to the contents or index in the book.

Comment: How "fractal"? Can you go beyond paragraphs here, or is that your smallest unit?

Comment: Actually, I'm more interested in wider groupings: book, library etc.

Comment: I'd use *division* for those in your original question, but beyond that one could very vaguely use *text*, but only vaguely. (This has shades of Jorge Luis Borges' "The Library of Babel").

Comment: Thanks John, *text* might work for me actually. Although, maybe it doesn't work so well for diagrams and images in the book. Sorry, my question was not well thought-through!

Comment: Well, *text* can cover any media in some uses, but not in others. As used in structuralism and post-structuralism, it may match your needs, or may not. (And I'm beginning to think you should check out that Borges story I mentioned, if you don't already know it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Part" or "Section" are of such general applicability that I think either would work.

"Idea" is a little too abstract; it doesn't really give a sense of a grouping of text.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, actually I want to be able to use the word to apply to the book as a whole too. I should have made that clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

"Part" is the most general term. Other options: "portion", "fragment", "fraction", "division"...

Comment: Thanks Consuela. Do you have any words that could be applied to the book as a whole too?

Comment: _Part_ can apply to a book, too – if the book is part of a trilogy.

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is an all-encompassing word to say what you want it to say.  The closest things I can think of are "Writings" or "Works".

Comment: I'm pondering on "an *explanation* (of an idea)". I think that might be suitably recursive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to define a document or part of it, so, why not "document part", "document unit", "document fragment", "document element".

Example. A document element consists of one or more document elements, each can be chosen from: book, chapter, section, paragraph, picture, table, ...

Note that with this recursive definition, a paragraph could consists of chapters of books of tables, etc.